# I dont see pop-up with usb connected

Tags: ubuntu-touch

During flash of Nexus 7 on step 3 of [install touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) on wiki.ubuntu.com

> 3.3 Plug the device into the computer via the USB cable.
>   Depending on the installed Android version, a popup will show up on the device with the host key that needs to be accepted for the device to communicate with the workstation.

**this wont show up**

USB debugging is on.....build is 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting adb.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
adb kill-server; adb start-server
```